# What would be the most efficient way to automate excel reports with lots of columns to send out via email?

Tags: sql-server, excel, sql-server-2012, excel-automation

I need to send via email multiple excel reports with approximately 60 to 100 columns.

Currently I am using SSRS to render it to excel and send out via emails.

But is there any more efficient way maybe?

Data generated by stored procedure in SQL.  All I need is just to send out chunk of data, no graphs no charts.

Comment: You can use SSIS packages to do it.  If the data changes often you can use a Script task (inside it use custom C# code) to convert the results from the SQL stored procedure to Excel.  I have done this but in .csv files.  Then use SSIS send email task to send out the emails

Comment: Thanks. So first part would be create Excel from SQL in put it in a folder. Then Send Mail Task will grab that file from the folder and send it to the user. Correct?  Is any way to NOT to store the file in a folder before sending it out?

Comment: I have never done it that way, but I know you could create the file, then once you send it in the email, use a file task to delete the file (if you didnt want to keep it after sending it)